# serverless framework command not working: "sls deploy -v"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, deployment, serverless-framework, aws-code-deploy

I am working on a project that involves the usage of Serverless Framwork and AWS. Although I am able to deploy my project successfully using the `sls deploy` command, but the sls deploy -v command fails to show me the deployment changes in my project.

Instead, it shows me something like this:

```
sls deploy -v
Framework Core: 3.24.1
Plugin: 6.2.2
SDK: 4.3.2
```

I want to see the changes in the deployment using the -v flag in the command. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v3 release of Serverless Framework, `-v` is no longer a shortcut for `--verbose` flag. In order to keep the old behavior, use `sls deploy --verbose`.

You can see that change on the list of breaking changes for v3 release: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#-breaking-changes